# Comma usage: I put something, into my mouth

Tags: punctuation, commas

**I put something, into my mouth.**

I want to know commas can be used in this way.
Of course, the comma is not necessary, but I want to know some possibility.

**Sometimes, I put it, into my mouth, but usually, I put it, into my nose.**

Are these commas used correctly?

Comment: There is no reason whatever to use a comma there..

Comment: @KateBunting Please answer under the preposition that I should use a comma please I'm begging.

Comment: Why do you think a comma might be OK there? Are you trying to follow a rule? Did you see a native speaker write like that? Did you hear someone talk as if there's a comma there?

Comment: @gotube Yes I read Gulliver's travels, but there are too many commas.

Comment: Where in Gulliver's Travels did you find a comma in a place like that?

Comment: @gotube Yes I think so

Comment: Please cite a real sentence from Gulliver's Travels with a comma like this one, or this question is merely a request for proof-reading, which is off-topic here

Comment: It's like listening to any speech by William Shatner in the original Star Trek ;))

Answer (score 2):

No, commas. They are simply not needed:

I put something in my mouth. [adverbial phrase]
I put something on the table. [adverbial phrase]

Sometimes I put it into my mouth but usually I put it into my nose.

(That sounds like drugs [ahem]).

**You don't interrupt the flow of an utterance when there is no reason to**. The phrases explain the action verb put.

Answer (score -2):

Always keep in mind these rules when using commas in English:

#### 1. Use a comma to **separate independent clauses**

You can use commas before a coordinating conjunction (but, yet, or, for ...) when it joins two ideas.

> **Example**: You can go watch the movie, or you can go play videogames.

---

#### 2. Use a comma **after an introductory clause or phrase**

You can use a comma after an introductory clause or phrase. In this case the comma says to the reader that the introductory clause has ended and the main sentence is about to begin.

> **Example**: When John was ready to eat, his friend called him to play.

---

#### 3. Use a comma **between all items in a series**

You can use a comma to separate each item in a series.

> **Example**: I want you to buy apples, meat, bananas and carrots for today's dinner.

---

#### 4. Use commas **to set off nonrestrictive clauses**

You can use commas to enclose clauses *not essential* to the meaning of a sentence.

These *nonessential* clauses are called **nonrestrictive** and are used with commas.
Clauses which are *essential* are called **restrictive** and are not used with commas.

Both restrictive and nonrestrictive clauses may begin with a relative pronoun (who, whose, that, which ..).

> **Example**: John Johanson, whose dog was lost two days ago, is turning 50 years old today. (*nonrestrictive*)
>
> **Example**: The dude who's talking is a well known actor. (*restrictive*)

---

#### 5. Use a comma **to set off appositives**

An *appositive* is a noun or a phrase that renames a nearby noun and gives **nonessential information**.
An appositive can be *nonrestrictive* and *restrictive*.

*Nonrestrictive*: The appositive is unnecessary to understand the identity of the noun or noun phrase it is identifying. They are used **with commas**.

*Restrictive*: The appositive is necessary to understand the identity of the noun or noun phrase that is being identified. They are **not** used **with commas**.

> **Example**: Alexander Pope, the Restoration poet, is famous for his monologues. (*appositive*)
>
> **Example**: The poet Pope is famous for his monologues. (*no appositive*)

---

#### 6. Use a comma **to indicate direct address**

You can use commas when a speaker in a sentence names the person to whom he is speaking. This is called direct address and is indicated with comma(s).

> **Example**: John, I think you’re wrong.
>
> **Example**: I think, John, you’re wrong.

---

#### 7. Use commas **to set off direct quotations**

In a dialog, if the **speaker** in the conversation is identified, his name, (or the noun or pronoun used to refer to the speaker), and the verb that refers to his speaking are enclosed within commas.

> **Example**: John said, “I don't dislike the gym because you can barely see results if not consistent.”
>
> **Example**: "I don't dislike the gym because you can barely see results if not consistent", he said.

---

#### 8. Use commas **with dates, addresses, titles, and numbers**

You can use commas with:

- **Dates**: The year is separated from the rest of the sentence with a pair of commas.

> **Example**: On December 25, 1998, John was born.

- **Addresses**: The elements of an address or place name are separated by commas. A zip code is not preceded by a comma.

> **Example**: Please send the letter to John at 123 Sfrinz Street, London, .

- **Titles**: If a title follows a name, separate the title from the rest of the sentence with a pair of commas.

> **Example**: John, love, could you take this for me?
>
> **Example**: Okay, boys, we are ready to go.

- **Numbers**: In numbers more than four digits long, use commas to separate the numbers into groups of three, starting from the right. (optional in four digits numbers)

> **Example**: 1,250 [or 1250]
>
> **Example**: 100,000

---

Considering all of this, I don't really find necessary to use a comma there, plus it does not end in any of the categories cited above.